# How to change column width of TimeLine Cell in DHTMLX - Scheduler .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scheduler, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I’m currently using [DHTMLX - Scheduler .NET](http://scheduler-net.com/docs/timelineview.html) in ASP.NET MVC.

How to set width of event cell in `TimelineView`?

I see that property **[`column_width`](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_createtimelineview.html?_ga=2.1822065.1727673003.1574945904-1683832737.1572056599) in Client side works fine**, But **Server side is not available this props.**

**Note:** Default width of this is 100px (I enabled horizontal scroll)

Now, *I wanna set from 100px to 50px.*

Does anyone have any idea for this issue ?

I really appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property was missing and was added only starting from v4.0.2 of the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/DHTMLX.Scheduler.NET/4.0.2 (published after your question)

So if you update the library to the latest version, you should be able to use `TimelineView.ColumnWidth` property on the server:

```
var timeline = new TimelineView("timeline", "section_id");
timeline.ColumnWidth = 90;
```